# SQL Server - materialised (indexed) view not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, materialized-view

I've created a materialised view in SQL Server, but when selecting from it I get the same performances and the same execution plan than when I select from the same query not "materialised".

The view is simple:

```
CREATE VIEW TestView WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT TAB_A.C1, TAB_A.C2, TAB_A.C3
FROM TAB1
INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.C2 = TAB2.C2
INNER JOIN TAB3 ON TAB2.C1 = TAB3.C1;


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestView
    ON TestView(C1, C2, C3);
```

Now, when I do something like

```
SELECT C1 FROM TestView
```

I'd expect to see in the plan only an access to the view and nothing else, instead it accesses the underlying tables like the view does not even exists.
I get exactly the same plan and the same execution time, too.

What am I doing wrong? If SQL Server cannot "materialise" the view, I'd expect to at least get an error when creating it.

Comment: Use the `NOEXPAND` hint: [Another Reason to Use NOEXPAND hints in Enterprise Edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints).

Comment: Materializing this view [buys you very little](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/#opt5). If it's just storing the results of the join with the same # of rows then the I/O cost will be similar (even if you add a NOEXPAND hint). The sweet spot for indexed views is when you aggregate a large number of rows into a small number of rows - in that case, accessing the view is much cheaper than calculating the aggregates manually each time. Also, [please always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @sp_BlitzErik noted in the comments, you need to use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint, like so:

```
SELECT something, something
FROM the.indexed_view WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

When SQL Server reads your query and replaces the name of the view with the definition of the view, that's what's known as "expanding" the view, so with `NOEXPAND`, you specifically tell SQL Server to not expand the view, but use the index that's there.

On the flip side, if there's no index (like if someone does `ALTER VIEW`!) the query will fail if you use `WITH NOEXPAND`.

Comment: This will force the plan to use the indexed view, but it is important to note that this doesn't mean performance will be better.

Comment: Although performance “almost always is better”, as the person who wrote and used the indexed view should be ‘smart’ enough to make the appropriate choice — especially given indexed view restrictions! SQL Server (at least though 2014) does a *terrible* job of electing NOT to expand indexed views. I now label all indexed views ..Indexed and explicitly use a noexpand. If the UCL is removed, I expect such queries to fail because the very-important-cluster is not being used. The (only?) downside is a misguided attempt to ‘bring a db up for application use’ while the important indices are not built.